# Live content in lightboxes doesn't look live

Tags: lightbox

In my website I'm displaying the websites I built as tiles that when clicked open as lightboxes.

[image]

I'm getting feedback that it's unclear that the lightboxes display actual live websites.

It's also unclear that they can be scrolled down and that links are active.

[image]

How can I make it more obvious to the user that the content in the lightboxes is live and interactive?

Answer (score 1):

Users expect components to [behave like other components they see on the web](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/match-system-real-world/), and we generally don't use lightboxes to open whole external websites. While you are doing this is a way that is very creative and innovative (the butterfly loader is lovely), users still might need to see the URL and other site-based information as they browse another site in order to trust where they are going.

I would recommend you use your lightbox, then, to tell the story of the site you built - your involvement in the project, and so on, with screenshots. Then, offer a link to each external site, which could open in a new tab if you are concerned with users still staying on your site while having a way to browse the sites you built.

Comment: thank you very much :)